# Console Application returns a weird value

Tags: c++

I'm currently programming a basic BMI calculator in C++, using classes etc. I have the basics coded, but when i run the program and enter my parameters, it returns a weird value (-9.25596e+061)

This is my main:

```
int main()
{
    h_bmi bmi;
    imperial calcImperial;
    metric calcMetric;

    char selection = '0';
    cout << "Hello! Welcome to the BMI calculator! This calculator will ask you a few \nquestions for it to calculate your BMI!" << endl; 
    cout << "\n \nWould you like to use metric (Kilograms and meters) or would you like to use \nimperial (pounds and inches) measurements? (m/i)" << endl;
    cin >> selection;

    if (selection == 'm' || 'M')
    {
        cout << "Enter your weight in kilograms: " << endl;
        cin >> calcMetric.weight;
        cout << "Enter your height in meters: " << endl;
        cin >> calcMetric.height;
        cout << calcMetric.bmi << endl;
    }
    else if (selection == 'i' || 'I')
    {
        cout << "Enter your weight in pounds: " << endl;
        cin >> calcImperial.weight;
        cout << "Enter your height in inches: " << endl;
        cin >> calcImperial.height;
        cout << calcImperial.bmi << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter only 'm' for Metric, or 'i' for imperial!" << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This is my h_bmi.h

```
#pragma once
class h_bmi 
{
public:
    double height, weight, bmi;
    h_bmi(){};
    ~h_bmi(){};
};
```

and my imperial.h (i've included this in my cpp file)

```
#include "h_bmi.h"
#include <cmath>
#pragma once
class imperial : public h_bmi
{
public:
    double calcBMI(double height, double weight)
    {
        bmi = (weight * 703) / (pow(height, 2));
        return bmi;
    };

};
```

metric.h:

```
#include "h_bmi.h"
#include <cmath>
#pragma once
class metric : public h_bmi
{
public:
    double calcBMI(double height, double weight)
    {
        bmi = weight / (pow(height, 2));
        return bmi;
    };

};
```

So like I said, when I run the program, I type in "m", then "80" and then "1.8" but it couts this value. 
If anyone could tell me the error and point me in the right direction, or possibly find me a fix, It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about changing `if (selection == 'm' || 'M')` with `if (selection == 'm' || selection == 'M')` and actually calling `calcBMI()`?

Comment: I called calcBMI like so:  
`cout << calcMetric.calcBMI(calcMetric.weight, calcMetric.height) << endl;`

but it still returns a strange value (this time it's 0.00028125)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have forgotten to actually call `calcBMI()`

Comment: I called calcBMI like so:  
`cout << calcMetric.calcBMI(calcMetric.weight, calcMetric.height) << endl;`

but it still returns a strange value (this time it's 0.00028125)

Comment: You have weight and height the wrong way around in the parameters

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked :D I'll do my best not to overlook that next time :)

Comment: Get to know your debugger a bit, so you can step through the code a line at a time, watching how the variable values change.  If you don't have a debugger, then just liberally sprinkle around some "cout"s so you can see what's going on :)